# BigQuery Paramaterized Search

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to use paramaters in a SQL statement to BigQuery.

I am using the code I found on https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries
I tried connecting to the same data table they used and to my own.

Everything executes just fine, no errors pop up but no results either. I feel like I am doing some small thing wrong but cannot figure out what it is. Can anyone else?

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

def query_named_params(corpus, min_word_count):
    client = bigquery.Client()
    query = """
        SELECT word, word_count
        FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
        WHERE corpus = @corpus
        AND word_count >= @min_word_count
        ORDER BY word_count DESC;
        """
    query_params = [
        bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter('corpus', 'STRING', corpus),
        bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter(
            'min_word_count', 'INT64', min_word_count)
    ]
    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
    job_config.use_legacy_sql = False
    job_config.query_parameters = query_params
    query_job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config)

    query_job.result()  # Wait for job to complete

    # print the results.
    destination_table_ref = query_job.destination
    table = client.get_table(destination_table_ref)
    for row in client.list_rows(table):
        print(row.min_word_count)
```

SOLUTION

Here is the final code that works. The problem was that the examples given by google set both parts of the parameters with the same name (corpus AND corpus) etc. I had them swapped. I also needed to pass the parameter names in the final query. The below works just fine.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

def query_named_params(corpus, word_count):
    client = bigquery.Client()
    query = """
        SELECT word, word_count
        FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
        WHERE corpus = @corpus
        AND word_count >= @min_word_count
        ORDER BY word_count DESC;
        """
    query_params = [
        bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter('corpus', 'STRING', 'sonnets'),
        bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter(
            'min_word_count', 'INT64', 126)
    ]
    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
    job_config.use_legacy_sql = False
    job_config.query_parameters = query_params
    query_job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config)
    r = query_job.result()  # Wait for job to complete
    for row in r:
        print(row)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    query_named_params('corpus', 'min_word_count')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works instead:

```
(...)
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.use_legacy_sql = False
job_config.query_parameters = query_params
query_job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config)

r = query_job.result()  # Wait for job to complete
for row in r:
    print(row)
```

In your code you tried connecting to the temporary table to load the results which can be retrieved directly from `QueryResults`.

Comment: what is the value of `corpus` and `min_word_count` in your script?

Comment: I have tried several. Corpus = sonnets, min_word_count = 100. I have also tried the same script with different tables and variables but it doesn't ever print anything.

Comment: I just ran your exact code with the adaptation I proposed and it worked normally. Maybe there's some bug when you send values `corpus` and `min_word_count` to the `query_named_params` function?

Comment: Interesting. Well it makes me feel better knowing it works for someone. So here is the thing. Even if I take out the values and don't use the parameters it doesn't work. I can do simple queries just fine in other files I have written but there is something about this specifically that is causing an issue.

Comment: do you mind posting your whole script? as it seems it looks like the bug is on how your function is being called.

Comment: Sure thing, I just added an update to the original questiion.

Comment: how/where are you calling `query_named_params`?

Comment: As you can tell I am new to Python and BigQuery. Added another update above. Usually without query params that is how I would u call it. You are correct I wasn't doing it. When I added it in I received the noted error message.